# Inline scripting in SharePoint not working even after changing web.config

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

So, after a lot of searching I finally thought I enabled inline scripting on my sharepoint page (by changing the parser settings in web.config). However, the following still isn't working:

This:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Go!" id="GoBtn" OnClick="test()"/>
```

Should be calling this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

    function test()
    {       
        alert('Hello World!');                  
    }

</script>
```

But it's not. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`OnClick` attribute means server-side event.

You need:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Go!" id="GoBtn" OnClientClick="test()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried that and it's still not working. Any ideas on how I could debug it? I'm fairly new to web stuff and SharePoint in general (I'm using SharePoint Designer to do this).

Comment: Does any javascript error appear in the console? You can check the console by pressing F12 button - modern browsers have a built-in debugger and developer tools.

Comment: There is indeed an error! Any idea what this means?

    SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'test' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: Did not notice that <script> tag has runat="server" attribute (see the Aanchal's answer). Remove it. You will decorate <script> tag with this attribute if you want to write server-side code, not javascript.

Comment: Yes, I did remove that and it's still not working (gives the "not a function" error). This is so strange, it seems so simple.

Comment: Check page source, does it contains the function?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing runat="server" from your script tag . There is no need for this .